# Sphere / Simple Gravity (relative magnitude) - Push-back force C++

Tags: c++

To save time in my game with pathfinding, I have a lower quality pathfinder, but the way units move between points is direct using

```
double distance = sqrt(xDistance * xDistance + yDistance * yDistance + zDistance * zDistance);
util_timer_movedelay += updatetime;
if (util_timer_movedelay > speed / 1000)
{

//  cout << "Distance:" << distance << endl;
    if (distance > 0.05)
    {
        unit_x += (0.5 * xDistance * speed * updatetime / distance);
        unit_y += (0.5 * yDistance * speed * updatetime / distance);
        unit_z += (0.5 * zDistance * speed * updatetime / distance);
        util_timer_movedelay = 0;

    }
```

Diagram
I would like help with a formula to help 1 push objects away from the sphere, but also attract objects to the sphere, now I already know how to calculate the distance that is easy as the above method is also spherical.

precision is an issue, due to the nature of how I've developed my game and the engine, the units are very compact, I'm having to use .3 float accuracy, so being as accurate as is reasonable is important (don't want to get stuck inside the planet or too far away for my path-finding to work), I don't want to push out 1 whole unit of location if the units on the surface of the globe are only 0.5 units in.

And obviously this would be able to work in the same way for the opposite direction yes ?

Basically simple question, how do I find the relative magnitude off distance for my red dot in the diagram to move exactly to the surface, or as close as possible. Should I just project a dot outwards ? I'm unsure / can't remember how to translate the point outwards relative to the sphere.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be as simple as normalizing the vector.

```
offset = interpolatedPoint - sphereCenter

snappedPoint = sphereCenter + offset * sphereRadius/offset.length
```

Dividing by the vector's length gives you a unit vector (length = 1), and multiplying by the sphere radius gives you a vector precisely on the surface of the sphere (up to numeric precision).

You can subtract your original interpolatedPoint to get the correction vector.

Comment: Sorry this may seem like a stupid question, which ones are which @DMGregory♦ ? snapped point, i assume the interpolated point is mid point in diagram.

Comment: Interpolated Point is the point at the end of the green vector in your diagram, partway between your start and end points. SnappedPoint is the point we get after snapping it to the surface of the sphere (at the tip of the red arrow in the diagram)

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in my solution code based on answer above

```
// offset from centre 
CVector3 cen{ 0,0,0 };
CVector3 unitvec{ unit_x,unit_y,unit_z };
float mag = dist2(unitvec, cen);
if (mag < 20.2 && CUnitType != Aircraft) // if distance to globe is less than 21 units- execute (saves process time) as this executed every second
{
    CVector3 offset{ cen,unitvec }; // construct as a vector between 2 vectors
    CVector3 newpoint = cen + offset * (AWorld.planet_radius)/ offset.Length();
    (*UnitModel)->SetPosition(newpoint.x, newpoint.y, newpoint.z); // offset new position
    unit_x = newpoint.x;
    unit_z = newpoint.z;
    unit_y = newpoint.y;
}
```